# Solr, update field attribute - multivalued

Tags: solr, schema, multivalue

I have in schema (Solr 5.1):

```
<field name="category" type="tint" indexed="true" stored="true"  
       multiValued="false" docValues="true" />
```

I want:

```
<field name="category" type="tint" indexed="true" stored="true" 
       multiValued="true" docValues="true" />
```

Can I update field to multiValued="true" without reindex all index?
The structure index will be valid after the upgrade?

Comment: You can update filed definition `multiValued=true` using schema API.  but you have to reindex docs, you can also check with partial update of document(updating a single field in the index).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you could try to just change schema without reindexing, but that could cause nasty errors.

Quote from the official Solr guide:

> When modifying the schema with the API, a core reload will
>   automatically occur in order for the changes to be available
>   immediately for documents indexed thereafter.  Previously indexed
>   documents will not be automatically updated - they must be re-indexed
>   if existing index data uses schema elements that you changed.
>
> If you modify your schema, you will likely need to re-index all
>   documents. If you do not, you may lose access to documents, or not be
>   able to interpret them properly, e.g. after replacing a field type.
>   Modifying your schema will never modify any documents that are already
>   indexed. You must re-index documents in order to apply schema changes
>   to them.  Queries and updates made after the change may encounter
>   errors that were not present before the change.  Completely deleting
>   the index and rebuilding it is usually the only option to fix such
>   errors.